# Not able to iterate over HashMap key?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I have a `HashMap` defined like this

```
linkcategory = new HashMap<Integer, List<CategoryTable>>();
```

As you can see every key points to a `List` object. And when I am trying to iterate over key nothing is showing up. Here is my JSP code.

```xml
<s:iterator value="linkcategory[#linklist.linkid]">
    <small>
        <span class="label label-info">
           <s:iterator value="value">
               <s:property value="categoryname"/>
           </s:iterator>      
        </span>
    </small>
</s:iterator>
```

The purpose is to print the categories of each link. So I don't want to iterate over the list for every link but to get the category list from map correspond to the link and print only that list.

Comment: when I use value="linkcategory" its prinitng all categories to every link.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a property `linkid` in the action class and use it to get the category list by the key, then iterate the categories.

```
<s:iterator value="linkcategory[linkid]">
  <small><span class="label label-info">
    <s:property value="categoryname"/>     
  </span></small>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Thanks Roman. I found the solution. I am now using `<s:set name="links" value="linkcategory[#linklist.linkid]"`. and then iterating over `links`